# Rails match routes with slugs without using ID in link

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, slug

In my routes file I can easily put together a match that looks like this and works just fine

```
match '/:slug/:id' => "pages#show", :id => :id
```

the link in the view that this works for is

```
link_to n.name, "/" + n.slug + "/" + n.id.to_s
```

I'd rather not include the ID number in the URL so I was hoping to do something like

```
match '/:slug' => "pages#show", :slug => :slug
```

But the problem is this doesn't provide the id to the pages show controller. Is there some way of using the :slug to match it to the page in the database with this slug to find the :id so I can pass the :id to the controller?

Answer (score 6):

In your routes use this

```
match "/:slug" => "pages#show"
```

And in your controller find the page by slug using this

```
@page = Page.find_by_slug(params[:slug])
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also do this:

```
resources :pages, only: :show, param: :slug
```

which will generate

> page   GET   /pages/:slug/(.:format)   pages#show

I order to be able to use this helper like this: `page_path(page)`, where page is an instance of `Page`, you also need to override the `to_param` method like so:

```
def to_param
  slug
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Maybe you should add that you need to change your `params[:id]` method to `params[:slug]`

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at https://github.com/norman/friendly_id gem, it simplifies routing with slugs a lot.