# Short url with Ruby on Rails routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I am trying to create short url links for books in Ruby on Rails. I want to get something like this: `www.domain.com/book123`, where `book` is the controller name (or custom controller name) and `123` is an id of the book.

Right now my routes look as follow:

```
resources :books, except: [:edit], path: "book" do
  put :new, on: :new
  member do
    get ':id'           => 'books#show'
    get 'general'       => 'books#general'
    get 'additional'    => 'books#additional'
    get 'photos'        => 'books#photos'
    get 'map'           => 'books#map'
  end
  resources :photos, only: [:create, :destroy]
end
```

This is what I get: `http://localhost:3000/book/40` or `www.domain.com/book/40`.

I was trying to find similar questions and I found that the only way to achieve this is to use regex. I am new in Ruby on Rails and I want to find the right and efficient way of doing it.

Also, I might be wrong but I've noticed that some of the urls can affect on the website performance, so I don't want to have such problems.

Any help, information or examples will be highly appreciated. Thank you for your help and time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails match routes with slugs without using ID in link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11355220/rails-match-routes-with-slugs-without-using-id-in-link)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this route:

```
get 'book*id' => 'bookscontroller#show'
```

Check this article: https://www.railsmine.net/2014/10/route-globbing-in-ruby-on-rails.html

Comment: Maybe I am doing something wrong, but it doesn't change routes at all. Thank you very much for your help, I will read this article anyways :)

Answer (score 1):

As @qdx47 has mentioned you'd better follow convention, but if you must not, I think you can override `to_param` on book model, like:

```
 def to_param
  "book#{id}"
 end
```

and then define routes like

`get ':id', to: 'books#show', constraints => { :book_id => /book[0-9]+/ }`

Answer (score 1):

I think you can give a try to below gem.

[Friendly Id Gem](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id)

Then you will be able to generate slug that can be any unique string. By default it will be uuid but you can override it. Follow gem documentation. It will allow you generate routes like http://localhost:3000/books/book123.

Comment: Thank you for the response and time. I will take a look at this `gem`.

Comment: Give a try to below gems. May they help you.
1. https://github.com/jpmcgrath/shortener
2. https://github.com/zigotto/googl

Answer (score 0):

In general, I think you would be going against convention and best practices by formatting your route in this way.

With that caveat, you should be able to define a route like so:

`get(':book_id', 'books#show', constraints => { :book_id => /book[0-9]+/ })`

You would then need to extract the id from the 'book' literal in the controller.

Comment: This answer seems right, but I am getting an error: `LocalJumpError, no block given (yield)`